# Call ArcPy.arcpy.StripMapIndexFeatures_cartography for specific feature within layer?

Tags: arcpy, query, strip-map

I'm creating a custom python script, and having trouble calling the script on a specific route within a layer

```
routekeyfield = 'route_ID'
routename = 'I95 NB'

routeslayer = "C:\\Projects\\\\Routes2017.mdb\\Routes"
# table = arcpy.CreateTable_management("in_memory", "stripMaps")
#memoryFeature = "in_memory\\stripMaps"
memoryFeature = "c:\\path\\stripmaps.mdb\stripmapsstuff"

#query the routes layer for the specific route
fields = ["SHAPE", routekeyfield]
whereclause = routekeyfield + " = '" + routename + "'"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(routeslayer, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.StripMapIndexFeatures_cartography(in_features=row, out_feature_class=memoryFeature, use_page_unit="NO_USEPAGEUNIT", scale=str(currentextentscale), length_along_line=str(currentextentwidth) + " Meters", length_perpendicular_to_line=str(currentextentscale) + " Meters", page_orientation="HORIZONTAL", overlap_percentage="10", starting_page_number="1", direction_type="WE_NS")
```

I'm not exactly sure how to filter the layer for a specfic route. Note, I'm using this script from a standalone script. Anybody have some ideas?
`

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. It seems like you've started to build the whereclause for your SearchCursor, but didn't implement it.

Change your SearchCursor line to the following:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(routeslayer, fields, where_clause = whereclause) as cursor:
```